Nuget Not available source but installed
im trying to build a project with a machine without internet connection, I realized the necessary packages are installed but Not available source message is being showed, when Im trying to build it it doesn´t resolve the packages. I checked the path of the local package source and it doesn´t have the screenshot packages but they are already installed so they are not needed in that directory right?
nuget package screenshot
